# ng slim loader to repeat 3 times when click on link

Tags: angular, slim, loader

I have integrated the angular slim loader on our application, it is working fine but i want the loader to repeat 3 or 2 times while click on the page link.

i am using this below code on ts file and html file, and i want to be below link, please help me regarding this improvement , thanks in advance

https://vaadin.com/

```
<ng2-slim-loading-bar [color]="'blue'" [height]="'4px'"></ng2-slim-loading-bar>

startLoading() {
    this.slimLoadingBarService.start(() => {
      console.log('Loading complete');
    });
  }
  finishLoading(){
    this.slimLoadingBarService.complete();
  }

  navigationInterceptor(event): void {
    if (event instanceof NavigationStart) {
      this.startLoading();
    }
    if (event instanceof NavigationEnd) {
      this.finishLoading();    }
    if (event instanceof NavigationCancel) {
      this.finishLoading();
    }
    if (event instanceof NavigationError) {
      this.finishLoading();
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

From what you've described the simplest way might be to use an *ngFor loop to create multiple elements.

In your `.ts` file

```js
repeat = [];

constructor(){
  this.repeat.length = 3
}
```

In your HTML

```html
<ng2-slim-loading-bar *ngFor="let instance of repeat" [color]="'blue'" [height]="'4px'"></ng2-slim-loading-bar>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. i tried but it is not working what i need , i want the slim loader to repeat 3 times like the demo website which i given above, i need the loader should be display 3 times during the page load   , please check on this site ,https://vaadin.com/

Comment: The loading bar length is based on 'progress', and isn't designed to loop. I think you are seeing it repeat on the vaadin site because the loader is being called by separate synchronous processes.